# How do I JIT the trampoline intrinsic using the llvm JIT engine?

Tags: llvm, jit, llvm-ir

I'm trying to JIT the llvm [trampoline intrinsics](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#trampoline-intrinsics), but I can't find the functionality for that in the [`llvm::IRBuilder class`](http://www.llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html). Does anyone know if it's possible to do with the current JIT engine?

I'm not looking for the semantics of the trampoline intrinsic, but how to generate the llvm ir for it. I assumed I would find it in the `llvm::IRBuilder` class because it can generate some other intrinsics, but, alas, it isn't there.

Comment: You need to find the intrinsic ID name from  llvm/IR/Intrinsics.gen then pass that to `Intrinsic::getDeclaration` which will give you a function object that you can pass to `IRBuilder::CreateCall`

Comment: Here is how you get the `Function*` for an intrinsic. Everything else is done by the `CallInst` or the `IRBuilder`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569967/adding-intrinsics-using-an-llvm-pass